# Import Entities

Tags: 7, importing-exporting, entities

I'm looking for method of importing an Entity Configuration. I'm using ECK to build my Entity Types and Bundles. But I have a project where I need to create an entity with a rather large number of fields.

I would like to be able to build my fields in a CSV format for example and then Import the fields into Drupal to create my Entity.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Many thanks for your help.